# Tips on how to make the strumming on guitar pro sound more like the guitar in the recording or is this the best it can be?

Tags: guitar-pro

Here is the sound I'm going for

I already have the tab down, I'm just trying to make it sound more like the original, soft and strummed. Not sure what the best settings are

[Here's what it sounds like on guitar pro](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgf5wtow5qk6a2u/sound.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: At what point is the example fingerpicked? Sounds like it's strummed with a pick, and at times it's strummed actually pretty hard.

Comment: I meant strummed lol sorry

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your notation looks like? What version of Guitar Pro is this?

Comment: Guitar Pro's RSE should help with this, as will modifying dynamics, ghost notes and directional strumming.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a novice Guitar Pro user, but it seems that at least in version 7.5, getting good sounding strumming playback requires you to manually tweak each strum's direction, speed and dynamics separately. Strumming is called "brushing" in the program, and there's an "Auto Brush" feature, but it doesn't seem to be of much help - you'll have to specify all the details anyway.

The notation will end up looking like a mess such as this:

[image: Guitar Pro strumming pattern]

You'll want to keep that for playback purposes only and not actually show it to anyone. ;)

The notes are produced by using the brush up/down "effects", and each time you specify such an effect for a note/chord, you're presented with this settings dialog where you tell the program the speed of this particular strum:

[image: BRUSH DOWNSTROKE]

This is very tedious, but luckily it seems that you can change all the notes while keeping the brushing effect information for that note/chord. So, once you get one bar of strumming to sound good, you can copy-paste the bar for the whole song and change the notes to what you actually want.

[image: GuitarPro brushing example with notes changed]

If you already have the tab done, you'll have to redo the notes in the copied strumming pattern.

To be honest, even with copy/pasting patterns, I think this is fairly cumbersome, the tweaking possibilities are very limited, and the result doesn't sound very convincing. If you want more realistic guitar strumming for producing music, there are programs such as MusicLab RealGuitar and AAS Strum.

Answer (score 2):

- In the Track panel (shortcut: F6), there are a few options that changes the sound. You probably want to play with the "playing style" options, try "fingers".
- Also in the Track panel, you can change the sound preset: under "Sounds" click on the preset name, I see there is a "fingers" preset. It may be better.
- Make sure you selected the right dynamic : Edition palette (shortcut: F2) or Note menu => Dynamic, try "mp" or lower. To be more realistic, you should assign different dynamic to each strum (up is usually lighter, strum on beat is usually the hardest)

It won't be perfect though.

Comment: Assigning different dynamics to individual notes like you said is a big step. I don’t know this program but I’m wondering if there is any type of strumming setting or arpeggiator. Without the subtle differences in timing of the individual strings on up and down strums it’s never going to sound quite right.

Comment: There are 2 strumming settings that can help : on a chord, you can activate "Arpeggio down" / "Arpeggio up" (ctrl-shift-d /ctrl-shift-up) in the Edition palette, or try "Auto brush" or "Accentuation" options on the Track panel.

Answer (score -2):

I'm at work and only listened to about 5 seconds (awaiting work). I'm also not entirely sure if you're talking computer settings for publishing or when you are playing it yourself. Below is my advice for playing it.

I'd always suggest a compressor for clean sound. I use a surf and turf compressor for this very reason. I put it at the front of my chain (pedal 1) that way there's a nice clean signal running through my chain.  It's always on because it gives me that nice John Mayer sound but it also elevates my distortion (pedal 2) when I switch to metal riffs.

After that, if you've an equalizer, curve down the left/bottom end (low freq).

After that, amp settings. Bass 5, treble 6/ Bass 6, treble 7... and so on. Set your bass one below your high is the point. The difference between 2/3, 3/4, 4/5 and so on requires a calculus explanation I'm just not up for. Just try each to taste.

Comment: How does this relate to Guitar Pro?

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with the question. -1 OP is asking how to get GuitarPro's MIDI playback to produce better acoustic guitar strumming.